# background image URL path

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a background for my page using CSS. The image is from another folder and I am trying to reference the image in CSS file.

The CSS file URL is /vowel-temp/administrator/templates/vowel/css .

The image file URL is /vowel-temp/administrator/templates/vowel/images/icons .

Why I can't see my background image?

`ul#menu li:first-child a:before{
    background-image: url("../images/icons/01-dashboard.png");
}`

Comment: How are you referrencing the image in your code?

Comment: Can you update your html and css code.

Comment: You probably need to use ../images/icons/ + the image file name

Answer (score 0):

Just use this as your url : "/images/vowel/imagename.jpeg".
you might be using the whole path so that might be the reason of your error.!

Comment: i tried the suggested solution but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
body {
    background-image: url("/images/vowel/imagename.jpeg");
}
```

Why do you have `ul#menu li:first-child a:before` as what you are trying to style?

Answer (score 0):

try to do that from another element if it's working or not

```
body {
    background-image: url("../images/icons/01-dashboard.png");
}
```

or add this to your code. since you're using :before pseudo-element

```
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
```

then add a relative position to 
`ul#menu li:first-child a`